# How I can deploy my new DAG to Airflow in live server through GitHub repository?

Tags: github, airflow, airflow-webserver

I am struggle to find out how deploy my Dag file to live server Airflow. I am very new to it and still learning how the ops going.
I would love to know some kinds of CI/CD for Airflow.

1. How to elaborate the Dags folder and other folders that deployed in GitHub repository and update the airflow DAGs in live server on git push ?
2. Is there anyway to deploy my DAG file through airflow web server?

For now I am still using manual method that upload the DAG file to the live server using ssh connection. I think this is not good practice for sustainable environment.

Comment: What platform have you hosted your Airflow instance on? What does your stack look like? Is there a CI/CD implementation already in place? Could you provide more details about your Airflow setup - Version, Configuration, etc?

Comment: The VM in the server is using Cent OS Linux, the airflow running through Docker in the virtual machine. There is no running CI/CD for a while especially for the airflow DAGs management. Maybe for the detail airflow setup I just following the template from airflow documentation itself. @VinayKulkarni
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#build-build-image